# How to delay JSoup for 5 seconds so I can access a website?

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

So I'm trying to parse the website [Kissanime.to](http://kissanime.to/), which is protected by Cloudflare, with JSoup. Whenever I go through the normal connection/start up procedures and try to retrieve the website title, I always get the words: "Please wait 5 seconds..." Anyway to delay JSoup AFTER it connects to the website so it can access the real website and not just the Kissanime start-up page? Also, if this problem gets solved, is there any way to spoof that javascript is enabled on JSoup in case that is also a restriction?

Code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://kissanime.to/").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0").ignoreHttpErrors(true).followRedirects(true).timeout(100000).ignoreContentType(true).get();

Thread.sleep(10000);

System.out.println(doc.title());
```

Result:

```
Please wait 5 seconds...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**This is not a duplicate because I'm eventually going to port this to Android and can't use a JavaFX application. Furthermore, I want to search something on the webpage and get another web page and the solution proposed will just give me static html.**

Comment: It sounds wasteful but apparently the second hit is faster than the first one, so you could just call `Jsoup.connect` twice

Comment: Scratch that, I tried programmatically and it did not work

Comment: @Dici Yea, I tried that, too. No luck :(

Comment: I'm currently trying to open a stream manually and then give it to Jsoup. However, I'm getting a 403 when I try to connect.

Comment: Yea, you have to put a userAgent. The one I put ("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0") seemed to work. Also, the other stuff I added to the connection (ingoreHttpErrors, followRedirects, etc.) also seem to prevent the 403.